# XPath Expression Returns Nodes When It Shouldn't

Tags: c#, xpath, .net-core

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
<parent>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

If I'm at the `<child>` node, I would expect the following XPath to return empty:

`./parent::*[not(parent)]`

However, the result set I'm getting lists the parent of the child. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `not(parent)` checks if the `parent` node is an empty element.
In your case it is not, because it contains a `child` node.

The expression you're looking for is probably `not(self::parent)` which checks if the node itself is not a `parent` node. So the whole expression should probably be

```
parent::*[not(self::parent)]
```

I removed the `./` axis because it wasn't necessary in this case.

Comment: You're assuming you know what the desired result of the query is. I don't know how you worked that out, because the OP didn't tell us. More specifically, the OP told us they were "at the child node", and this expression doesn't do anything useful when the `<child>` element is the context node.

Comment: You really made me thinking about that :-) In my understanding, the context node is `<child>` and he wanted to exclude its parent element from the result set if it's a `<parent>` - meaning an empty set.